# Dynamics NAV 2013 - Adding Extra Fields to Customer Card

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

Because you aren't allowed to alter the customer table, I have created a new table 'Extra Customer Info' and made a CardPage bound to that table.

I then included that in the original customer page, so the customer card now has an extra fast tab called extra customer table, however the fields in that fasttab are greyed out, and I can't type anything in them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a end user you should be able to add fields to the customer table, but you have to give these new fields a fieldnumber within the 50000-range.

If you have no custom field yet, the first field would be:

Enabled =Yes
Field No. = 50000

Comment: I am adding [this link](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/f/34/t/210417) for future reference (similar question, similar answer).